# wxpython, open file and display text into textctrl area

Tags: wxpython

Pretty new to wxpython so i am struggling with this. I have got a little way with the help of tutorials and trying to learn.

I have an "open" in my file menu, and i am trying to get it so that when i open a file, the text in the file will be shown in my multiline textctrl box

I have tried a few bits such as WriteText() and SetValue() but can't get it to display.

```
import wx
import os



class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, title):
    self.dirname=''
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(450, 450))
    self.CreateStatusBar() # A Statusbar in the bottom of the window
    global urlFld

    self.InitGUI()
    self.Centre()
    self.Show()

def InitGUI(self):

    #MENUS
    fileMenu = wx.Menu()  #create menu for file
    viewMenu = wx.Menu()  #create a menu for view
    helpMenu = wx.Menu()  #create a menu for help

    #FILE MENU
    menuOpen = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "&Open"," Open a file to edit")  #add open to File
    menuExit = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "E&xit"," Terminate the program")  #add exit to File

    #VIEW MENU
    menuView = viewMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "TODO:", "Still to do")

    #HELP MENU
    menuAbout = helpMenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "&About", "About this program")  #add about menu item

    #MENUBAR
    menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
    menuBar.Append(fileMenu,"&File") # Adding the "filemenu" to the MenuBar
    menuBar.Append(viewMenu, "&View")
    menuBar.Append(helpMenu, "&Help")
    self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)  # Adding the MenuBar to the Frame content.

    '''#TOOLBAR
    toolbar = self.CreateToolBar()
    toolOpen = toolbar.AddLabelTool(wx.ID_OPEN, "Open", wx.Bitmap("open.png"))
    toolExit = toolbar.AddLabelTool(wx.ID_EXIT, "Exit", wx.Bitmap("blah.png"))'''


    #MENU EVENTS
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, menuOpen)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, menuAbout)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, menuExit)

    '''#TOOLBAR EVENTS
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.OnExit, toolExit)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.OnOpen, toolOpen)'''


    #PANEL
    panel = wx.Panel(self)

    panel.SetBackgroundColour('#ededed')
    vBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    hBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    hBox.Add(wx.StaticText(panel, label="File:"), flag=wx.TOP, border=3)
    hBox.Add(wx.TextCtrl(panel), 1, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)
    checkBtn = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Check")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.checkBtnClick)
    hBox.Add(checkBtn, 0, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)
    vBox.Add(hBox, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, border=10)
    vBox.Add((-1, 10))

    hBox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    hBox2.Add(wx.StaticText(panel, label="URLs:"))
    vBox.Add(hBox2, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)
    vBox.Add((-1, 5))

    hBox3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    urlFld = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE, size=(-1,295))
    hBox3.Add(urlFld, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
    vBox.Add(hBox3, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, border=10)


    panel.SetSizer(vBox)

#GUI EVENTS
def checkBtnClick(self, e):
    urlFld.SetValue(self, "blahh")

#MENU ITEM EVENTS
def OnAbout(self,e):
    dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "A small text editor", "My test editor", wx.OK)  #create a dialog (dlg) box to display the message, and ok button
    dlg.ShowModal()  #show the dialog box, modal means cannot do anything on the program until clicks ok or cancel
    dlg.Destroy()  #destroy the dialog box when its not needed

def OnExit(self,e):
    self.Close(True)  #on menu item select, close the app frame.

def OnOpen(self,e):
    self.dirname=""  #set directory name to blank
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file to open", self.dirname, "", "*.*", wx.OPEN) #open the dialog boxto open file
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:  #if positive button selected....
        self.filename = dlg.GetFilename()  #get the filename of the file
        self.dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()  #get the directory of where file is located
        f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'r')  #traverse the file directory and find filename in the OS
        text = f.read()
        self.urlFld.SetValue(f.read())  #open the file from location as read
        self.urlFld.WriteText(text)
        f.close
    dlg.Destroy()

app = wx.App(False)   #creates a new app
MainWindow(None, "URL Checker")  #give the frame a title
app.MainLoop()  #start the apps mainloop which handles app events
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urlFld` should be an attribute of the class:

```
# 'self' added
self.urlFld = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE, size=(-1,295))
```

and not a local variable so that you can reference it outside the method.

Comment: out of interest, what should i be using as best practice?
SetValue(f.read) or WriteText(text)??

Comment: See the code in my post method file_open, it uses self.urlFld.LoadFile

Comment: what is the difference between your version and my version, as in, why did you do it differently, and why is that way better?

Comment: Im using with to open the dialog so there is no need to destroy it , it does that automatically when its done with and i know how to set the text from the file your just guessing by trying different stuff.

Comment: except your code opens the load box twice. i select a file and click "Open" then it loads up the same open box and I have to select the same file and click "Open" again

Comment: In the code i posted file_open is only called once when OnOpen method is called by the evt_menu.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use Global variables use self instead here is modified code

```
import wx
import os



class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        self.dirname = ''
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(450, 450))
        self.CreateStatusBar()  # A Statusbar in the bottom of the window

        self.InitGUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def InitGUI(self):

        # MENUS
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()  # create menu for file
        viewMenu = wx.Menu()  # create a menu for view
        helpMenu = wx.Menu()  # create a menu for help

        # FILE MENU
        menuOpen = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN,
                        "&Open", " Open a file to edit")  # add open to File
        menuExit = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "E&xit",
                                " Terminate the program")  # add exit to File

        # VIEW MENU
        menuView = viewMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "TODO:", "Still to do")

        # HELP MENU
        menuAbout = helpMenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "&About",
                                "About this program")  # add about menu item

        # MENUBAR
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(fileMenu, "&File")  # Adding the "filemenu" to the MenuBar
        menuBar.Append(viewMenu, "&View")
        menuBar.Append(helpMenu, "&Help")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)  # Adding the MenuBar to the Frame content.

        '''#TOOLBAR
        toolbar = self.CreateToolBar()
        toolOpen = toolbar.AddLabelTool(wx.ID_OPEN, "Open", wx.Bitmap("open.png"))
        toolExit = toolbar.AddLabelTool(wx.ID_EXIT, "Exit", wx.Bitmap("blah.png"))'''

        # MENU EVENTS
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, menuOpen)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, menuAbout)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, menuExit)

        '''#TOOLBAR EVENTS
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.OnExit, toolExit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.OnOpen, toolOpen)'''


        # PANEL
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        panel.SetBackgroundColour('#ededed')
        vBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        hBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hBox.Add(wx.StaticText(panel, label="File:"), flag=wx.TOP, border=3)
        hBox.Add(wx.TextCtrl(panel), 1, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)
        checkBtn = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Check")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.checkBtnClick)
        hBox.Add(checkBtn, 0, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)
        vBox.Add(hBox, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT | wx.TOP, border=10)
        vBox.Add((-1, 10))

        hBox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hBox2.Add(wx.StaticText(panel, label="URLs:"))
        vBox.Add(hBox2, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)
        vBox.Add((-1, 5))

        hBox3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.urlFld = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE, size=(-1, 295))
        hBox3.Add(self.urlFld, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        vBox.Add(hBox3, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, border=10)


        panel.SetSizer(vBox)

    # GUI EVENTS
    def checkBtnClick(self, e):
        self.urlFld.SetValue("blahh")

    # MENU ITEM EVENTS
    def OnAbout(self, e):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "A small text editor",
                               "My test editor", wx.OK)  # create a dialog (dlg) box to display the message, and ok button
        dlg.ShowModal()  # show the dialog box, modal means cannot do anything on the program until clicks ok or cancel
        dlg.Destroy()  # destroy the dialog box when its not needed

    def OnExit(self, e):
        self.Close(True)  # on menu item select, close the app frame.

    def OnOpen(self, e):
        self.file_open()
        e.Skip()

    def file_open(self):  # 9
        with wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file to open", self.dirname,
                           "", "*.*", wx.OPEN) as dlg:
            if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
                directory, filename = dlg.GetDirectory(), dlg.GetFilename()
                self.urlFld.LoadFile('/'.join((directory, filename)))
                self.SetTitle(filename)

app = wx.App(False)  # creates a new app
MainWindow(None, "URL Checker")  # give the frame a title
app.MainLoop()  # start the apps mainloop which handles app events
```